# What is the latest sources.list for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, repository, source.list

[Raspbian Repository](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) suggests that Wheezy would be the "official" current suite of the Raspbian distribution.

I cannot believe that, though, because I have been using "Jessie" as "stable" instead for the last years, which is the successor of "Wheezy".

And since "Stretch" has been out, I changed my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the following:

```
$ find /etc/apt/sources.list* -type f | xargs sed '/^deb/!d'
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stable main contrib non-free rpi firmware
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

I also ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` from "Jessie" to "Stretch" successfully, which downloaded and installed about 1 gig of `*.deb` files as part of the process.

But even though `apt-get update` is able to fetch all the package lists without problems, I never got any updates for a week or so.

I cannot believe there have not been any security updates since then, so I am worried that my `/etc/apt/sources.list*` may be incorrect.

I tried changing back "Stretch" to "Jessie", but no updates either.

Can anyone tell me why I am obviously missing the latest security upgrades?

Comment: This was probablly my fault, sometimes the infrastructure snarls up for various reasons (though recent improvements mean it should happen less than it used to) and I don't always notice and unsnarl it as quickly as I should.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems my problem has been a temporary one.

Some weeks after posting my original question, the settings just started working. I did not actually do anything. I guess "stretch" was not really ready to be supported then under Raspbian, but now it is.

Currently, I have only the following effective lines in my sources.list, and they work fine now:

```
$ grep ^[[:alnum:]] /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi firmware
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Lession learned from this incident: Never trust distro maintainers to reliably change generic suite names like "stable" or "testing" in a consistent way. They may change the name in on repo, but not (yet) in the others you might be using as well.

Better use explicit suite names like "stretch", and change them manually when the next dist-upgrade has arrived. This can save you a lot of headaches during the transition period between the dist upgrades.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You just saved me so much time.

Comment: There is a spelling error on in stead of one.

Answer (score 3):

They have the new "Stretch" version out now.  You can find it [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/now-that-raspbian-stretch-has-been-released-should-jessie-users-rush-out-and-do)

That Q&A contains all the upgrade instructions.

> To upgrade, first modify the files /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list. In both files, change every occurrence of the word ‘jessie’ to ‘stretch’. (Both files will require sudo to edit.)

---

To answer your question, the latest repositories are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` - The uncommented line in NOOBS Jessie is:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

There is another that is commented out so is not in use by default.  It is identical except instead of `mirrordirector` it has `archive` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is seems my problems were of a temporary nature during the transition period to stretch. I can now use "stretch" everywhere and no further "jessie" is required. But it took a couple of weeks to get there.