# Error install raspberrypi-ui-mods

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-jessie, gui, mods

I am moving from Jessie to newer version Stretch followed this [What is the latest sources.list for Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69515/what-is-the-latest-sources-list-for-raspbian). I successfully update and upgrade. However, when I installed the raspberrypi-ui-mods and got this error.

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/emotes/face-wink.png`: Read-only file system
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/emotes/face-uncertain.png`: Read-only file system
...
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
unable to remove newly-extracted version of `/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/emotes/face-glasses.png`: Read-only file system
E: could not create temporary file for /var/lib/apt/extended_states - mkstemp(30: Read-only file system)
E: could not open file /var/lib/apt/extended_states - open(2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to open StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states
```

Here is the full error image
https://ibb.co/FXgkqYW

Here is my code in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi firmware
...
```

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
...
```

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would anyone WANT to "upgrade" from one obsolete OS to another? It was NEVER recommended to upgrade.

Comment: @Milliways I mean what if I want to install any packages using apt. How should I do it?